# How to convert Index column with name 'Date' to weekday name in dataframe. The index format is dtype: int64

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

How to convert Index column with name Data to weekday name in dataframe

[image]

Comment: Does the date correspond to weekdays? 0 to 6?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
daynumber = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
weekday = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
df = df.rename(index=dict(zip(daynumber,weekday)))
df
```

output:

```
Date       ...
Monday     ...
Tuesday    ...
Wednesday  ...
Thursday   ...
Friday     ...
```

Comment: Will it be possible to fix the code to show weekdays df_data = df_drop_b.groupby([df_drop_b.index.weekday]).mean()
print(df_data.head(5))